# Lowering indices of Riemann tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I'm trying to get the Riemann tensor with four covariant indices from the standard form given by,

$$R^l_{ikj}=\Gamma^l_{ij,k}-\Gamma^l_{ik,j}+\Gamma^m_{ij}\Gamma^l_{mk}-\Gamma^m_{ik}\Gamma^l_{mj}$$

Contracting with the metric, we have

$$R_{likj}=g_{ls}R^s_{ijk}=g_{ls}(\Gamma^s_{ij,k}-\Gamma^s_{ik,j}+\Gamma^m_{ij}\Gamma^s_{mk}-\Gamma^m_{ik}\Gamma^s_{mj})$$

Using the identity

$$g_{ls}\Gamma^s_{ij,k}=\Gamma_{ijl,k}-\Gamma^s_{ij}(\Gamma_{lks}+\Gamma_{skl})$$

it becomes

$$R_{likj}=\Gamma_{ijl,k}-\Gamma_{ikl,j}-\Gamma^s_{ij}(\Gamma_{lks}+\Gamma_{skl})+\Gamma^s_{ik}(\Gamma_{ljs}+\Gamma_{sjl})+\Gamma^m_{ij}\Gamma_{lmk}-\Gamma^m_{ik}\Gamma_{lmj}$$

I should arrive to,

$$R_{likj}=\Gamma_{ijl,k}-\Gamma_{ikl,j}+\Gamma^m_{ik}\Gamma_{ljm}-\Gamma^m_{ij}\Gamma_{lkm}$$

as given here: https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/diff_geom.pdf

However, I have no idea on how to combine the last four terms to give this, as I already have the first two terms. I've checked several pages here and on the web but so far I haven't found any proper proof using only indices. I've checked the following pages:

[Deriving Riemann tensor with four lower indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047966/deriving-riemann-tensor-with-four-lower-indices)

https://www.zweigmedia.com/diff_geom/Sec10.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVBxE4IJKHs

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378009/lower-raising-riemann-curvature-tensor

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485583/lowering-index-of-riemann-
tensor

[What is the definition of $R_{ijkl}$ in terms of metrics on a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638971/what-is-the-definition-of-r-ijkl-in-terms-of-metrics-on-a-manifold/639021#639021)

[Riemann tensor with all indices lowered on a 2D manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034371/riemann-tensor-with-all-indices-lowered-on-a-2d-manifold)
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484815/indices-of-the-riemann-tensor-of-the-first-kind

I also found someone try a proof here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309022/covariant-riemann-tensor-indices

However, he uses some weird identities such as

$$g_{ij,k}=\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}$$

which is false, since we can directly proof that,

$$\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}=g_{ki,j}+g_{kj,i}-g_{ij,k}$$

I really appreciate any help, I've been trying to prove this for over a month now, so this is my last resource.

Edit: one can also find this formula in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry) as:

$$R_{ilkm}=\frac{1}{2}(g_{im,kl}+g_{kl,im}-g_{il,km}-g_{km,il})-g_{np}(\Gamma^n_{kl}\Gamma^p_{im}-\Gamma^n_{km}\Gamma^p_{il})$$

which is analogous to the one shown above, just with an added metric tensor to have mixed indices in the Christoffel symbols (the expansion in terms of the metric tensor follows trivially from expanding the first two terms of Christoffel symbols with derivatives).

Comment: Your ultimate formula has an error, as there are extraneous $s,m$ in the final two terms. Can you please track down the correct formula to have here?

Comment: @TedShifrin I checked the formula (given in Markus Desernonotes on differential geometry) and it's exactly the same, you can check it in equation (1.25) of https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/diff_geom.pdf . I also checked the formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry and it's also the same, albeit with an additional metric tensor term so the Krisotffel indices have mixed indices, I'll add it to the post if you want. The extraneous $s,m$ are just dummy indices used in the contractions.

Comment: Sorry. I meant *your* last formula before Markus's formula to be arrived at. There is no contraction appearing in the last two terms. That's the whole problem.

Comment: Sorry, I mistunderstood. You're right, I wrote with the wrong contractions when copying from my notes, it's fixed now. However, I still have the problem on combining the terms with products of Christoffel symbols, I've tried several identities but so far they haven't worked.

Comment: You claim the correct result ends with $-\Gamma_{ik}^m\Gamma_{ikm}$, which is another obvious error: one of each of $i,\,k$ must be replaced with $j,\,l$ i some order for consistent indices.

Comment: OK, now the last term in the "correct" formula needs to be repaired.

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right again, I misspelled when I copied it. I fixed it now, the correct form is $\Gamma^m_{ik}\Gamma_{lkm}$, which only contracts with the dummy index $m$.

Comment: OK, this is my last complaint. I'm just losing interest in trying to do your due diligence. The formula for $R_{\ell ijk}$ should be, among other things, skew-symmetric in both pairs $\ell i$ and $jk$. So I am very skeptical about Markus's formula.

Comment: If you mean the signs, indeed I also copied them wrong so I corrected them (both in Markus and my formula). I checked again and all formulas should be correct. I've arrived at the first two terms, and I have no problem even arriving at the formula shown in Wikipedia for these. My question really lies if there's some unknown equation to combine the the Kristoffel symbols.

Comment: "However, he uses some weird identities such as ... which is false". To get the identity use that for a general tensor $A$ we have $\nabla_k A_{ij} = A_{ij,k} - A_{mj}\Gamma^m_{ik} - A_{im}\Gamma^m_{jk}$. Now take $A=g$ and use that the covariant derivative of the metric is zero. The confusion wrt this answer is probably that that answer or you are using different conventions to where to put the index you lower (first or last).

Comment: @Winther thank you. I see, then if we take the general form and set it to zero (since the covariant derivative of the metric is zero), then we have: $g_{ij,k}=g_{mj}\Gamma^m_{ik}+g_{im}\Gamma^m_{jk}$. Now lowering the indices, we get: $g_{ij,k}= \Gamma_{jik}+\Gamma_{ijk}$, which is similar to the one proposed above, except for the order of indices.